# How to Get Different Types from Child Classes

Tags: c#, oop

I am interested in making a series of classes that will store configuration values from a configuration file. These values can range in primitive types; boolean, string, int, etc...

I understand that this may be considered reinventing the wheel, but in addition to the configuration file reading, these classes also contain a logger, and the option to get the value via user input(if no config file is loaded).

The issue I am having is that my objects are stored in a dictionary of the parent class type, I cannot figure out how to extract the unique primitives from them. I understand that trying to output different values from the same method or property breaks polymorphism. I wanted to get some opinions on alternate suggestions on how to accomplish maintaining a container of objects that stored different primitive datatypes.

```
abstract class ConfigElement
{
    // same for all ConfigElements
    public static ILogger logger;
    public static bool useConfig;

    protected string _key;
    protected string _commandPrompt;

    protected ConfigElement(string key, string commandPrompt)
    {
        _key = key;
        _commandPrompt = commandPrompt;
    }

    abstract public void SetValue(string value);

    public static ConfigElement Create(string key, string commandPrompt, string inValue)
    {
        return new ConfigStringElement(key, commandPrompt, inValue);
    }

    public static ConfigElement Create(string key, string commandPrompt, bool inValue)
    {
        return new ConfigBoolElement(key, commandPrompt, inValue);
    }

}

class ConfigStringElement : ConfigElement
{
    public string Value;

    public ConfigStringElement(string key, string commandPrompt, string inValue = "") : base(key, commandPrompt)
    {
        this.Value = inValue;
    }

    override public void SetValue(string input)
    {
        Value = input;
    }

    public string GetValue()
    {
        if (!ConfigElement.useConfig)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_commandPrompt);
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Value = userInput;
        }
        logger.Information($"Config Element: {_key} value: {Value}.");
        return Value;
    }

    override public string GetConfigString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}

class ConfigBoolElement : ConfigElement
{
    public bool Value;

    public ConfigBoolElement(string key, string commandPrompt, bool inValue = false) : base(key, commandPrompt)
    {
        Value = inValue;
    }

    override public void SetValue(string input)
    {
        List<string> trueEntries = new List<string> { "yes", "y", "true", "t" };
        Value = trueEntries.Contains(input.ToLower());
    }

    public bool GetValue()
    {
        if (!ConfigElement.useConfig)
        {
            Value = GetTrueOrFalse(_commandPrompt);
        }
        logger.Information($"Config Element: {_key} value: {Value}.");

        return Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `in a dictionary`, alternatively it could be not a dictionary but a class/record with properties having different (specific) types, if it would be ok

Comment: If you want to support ANY type, then you're going to have to use reflection and casting or the "is"/"as" operators. If you only want to support a few different types, then you might want to consider a "discriminated union" approach using [`OneOf` on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OneOf)

Comment: @Renat, I initially did this. Had a class that had members of ConfigStringElements and ConfigBoolElements. The only bummer to this is now it becomes tedious add additional items and to load and save all of them.